# Get discrete MLE and check if its unbiased

Tags: inference

Suppose $X$  is a discrete random variable with $P(X = 1) = \theta $  and $P(X = 2) = (1-\theta)$

Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ and check if the estimator is unbiased

I got that $\theta_{MLE} = \frac{f_{1}}{n}$ with $f_{1}$ meaning number of times  $X_{i} = 1$ in the sample

For the expectation is this correct $E[\theta_{MLE}] = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X =1)}{n}$? This would allow me proof that $\theta_{MLE}$ is unbiased

Can $f_{1}= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} 1_{(0)}(X_{i})$?

Comment: Almost there, you count how many times $X_i$ is equal to one by adding the indicators that the $X_i$'s are equal to one, not to zero$$f_1=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb I_1(X_i)$$

Comment: Oh yeah I got that wrong, it is definetly (1) instead of (0). Thank you!